# how to validate a jquery modal form with php only & return message also in modal form

Tags: php, jquery

I was looking all over the place but couldn't find anything similar to what I need.
I am new to jQuery, but have some experience in php and I would want a php only validation of a form which is in a modal dialog as below. Then, the result needs to be displayed in the modal message with the id "dialog-message".
Could anyone please help as I'm sure I'm missing something.

**jQuery:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#load-my-modal").button().click(function() {
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function() {
            $("#test-form").submit();
            $(this).dialog("close");
            },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
});
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }   
    }
});
});
</script>
```

**The form:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<button id="load-my-modal">Open Modal Form</button>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Modal form">
    <p>All form fields are required!</p>
    <form id="test-form" name="test-form" action="submit.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**submit.php:**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(!empty($name) || !empty($email) || !empty($password)) {
    echo '
    <div id="dialog-message" title="All ok">All ok</div>';
    } else {
           echo '<div id="dialog-message" title="Fields are empty">Fields are empty</div>';
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do it through ajax without submitting the form, first validate it, if all goes well then submit it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment from @emiloprea.

```
$("#test-form").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var fields = $(this).serialize();
    $.post("submit.php", fields, function(data){
        $("#dialog-message").html(data);
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Something like this should do the trick :) Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I've found something like this before  and played with it but I thought this could not be the proper way. All I want to do is avoid client-side validation.

Comment: If I simply alert(data); instead of $("#dialog-message").html(data); $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");  then it seems to work, the difference would be that the returning result is not shown in a modal window, which would be more desirable.

Comment: Does the dialog not open?